# How to figure out where is the best place to store homemade cookies: in the fridge or on the counter, in an airtight container or elsewhere

Tags: storage-method, cookies

The other day I baked some Nutella cookies (the famous four ingredient recipe which calls for egg, Nutella, vanilla and flour), they tasted awesome but the next day they became hard and chewy. A little Google search and figured they must be stored in an airtight container in the fridge. I bake several types of cookies but I have problem storing them so that several unknown factors don't affect their taste and texture. How do you figure out where is the best place to store homemade cookies to preserve flavor? Does it depend on the ingredients, as in if there is milk, store in the fridge?

Comment: It's not solely ingredients, as sugar cookies have milk & butter, yet do fine out of the fridge.  Other cookies become problematic in the fridge (as they're too brittle & crumbly when cold), so it's not a universal solution, either.  It often takes a trial (and possible failure) to determine if you need to place things between layers of cookies, and how high you can safely stack them.  I used to have a lot of the Gladware 'family size' containers for my xmas cookie baking, but they went and changed the lid design, and they now take up ~2x the space to store.

Answer (score 3):

I worked in a professional bakery and also have baked massive amounts of cookies every year for Christmas for as far back as I can remember. My preferred method of storage is in airtight containers in the freezer and doling out however many cookies at a time as needed. I find that any baked goods that are frozen soon after baking will have the same characteristics as just-baked items. It's the only way that I can bake for a few weeks and give fresh cookies as gifts and send through the mail. There are a few varieties that I do need to layer between waxed paper sheets, like chewy oatmeal, but all the cookies I've ever made through the years come right back to life once defrosted.

Answer (score 2):

If the cookies are baked, I cool them completely. Then, I put them on a plate and under a cake dome. They look nice, don't get smashed or crumbled, keep their flavor, and maintain their texture for a few days.

I do not store baked cookies in the refrigerator because I have had problems with the cookies becoming dry (even in an airtight plastic bag).

If I don't need to bake all of the cookies at once, my best results come from freezing the cookie dough and baking on demand.

I mostly bake chocolate chip or sugar cookies. So, my answer is based on those types of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie jar came into being for a reason. It is a place to keep cookies in a controlled environment that is not so open as to dry the cookie out, but is not so air tight that moisture from the cookie can't escape the container.

Hard dry cookies (or at least harder and dryer than intended) are no good. And floppy crumbled cookies from sitting in a humid sealed container are no good either. Hence the cookie jar where cookies can be kept for weeks before completely drying out, but not losing their integrity due to being trapped in with their own moisture.

Comment: Cookie jars are horrid. I can't possibly stack my soft cookies 6-8 rows deep like that, they'd be crumbs by the time I got to the bottom. Cookie jars should be banned.

Comment: Then use a longer shallower tin, the concept however is the same. FYI however, although a cookie or two sometimes gets broken, I never had problems with a cookie jar. My aunt has a cookie Ttin that is about oh 20inches in diameter, but stacked so that each subsequent tin was the nested lid of the layer below with a final lid on top. It was ingenious. Chocolate chip cookies lasted for weeks before becoming hard.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The cookie jar is only good for the type of cookie which needs a cookie jar. Something like lady fingers or speculatius won't fare well in a cookie jar. You never addressed how one knows which cookies go in the jar and which don't.

Comment: @rumtscho: I think this answer is implying that the cookie jar should be used for all types of cookies. I don't agree, but that's how I interpreted this answer.